# G's order is a multiply of coprime numbers, need to prove about its subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

dont want you to answer me directly, only a direction of thinking.

I have abelian $G$ of finite order $np : p>n, p>1,$ and p is prime.
$A,B\le G$ are sub-groups of G of order $p$ both.

I need to decide what is true (and prove it):$$$$
$A\cap B=\left\{e\right\}$ or $A=B$

So what I defintly see: $(n,p)=1$

And my thinking direction was: 
Lets look on AB. G is abelian, so AB must be a sub-group of it. Now let supose the intersection is ${e}$. So $|A\cap B=1|$, then $|AB|=|A|*|B|=p^2$.
$$$$ And that is bigger then $np$, but the order of a sub-group must at least devide the order of the group and definitly be lesser then it. 
So as I conclude from that, the intersections isnt only ${e}$ and they must be even.

So dont give me an answer, just point me where I do get wrong in my thinking, if I do.

Comment: You may also want to add something about why it must be the case that $A\cap B=\{e\}$ or $A=B$, and there is no third option.

Comment: You just read my thoughts, I was just editing it. Correct me if I wrong, but I want to say that A and B are cyclic, so if just one element that isnt the identity is in another sub-group, it must be the whole second sub-group. But I try to explain myself why. G is Abelian so A and B are eather. Let me think about it for a couple of moments.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like a hint, but you are definitely close.

Comment: It is not because $A$ and $B$ are cyclic that their intersection is $A$ (or $B$).

Comment: @Bernard In general, that's true. In this case, it is enough that they are cyclic since they have prime order, so if their intersection is anything more than the identity, it must be everything.

Comment: Oh, Ben, there is such hypothesis, isnt it? 
If an order of a group is prime, it is cyclic, right ?

Comment: And more importantly, it has only two subgroups (cyclicity is not essential here).

Comment: @Ilya.K. Yes, if the order of a group is prime, it must be cyclic. Can you think of a good reason why?

Comment: @Bernard It isn't necessary, but you may as well use it if you've got it.

Comment: It's only sub-groups are the trivial, thats I know for sure. Otherwise, if it wasnt cyclic, must be any other sub-groups, arent they ? 
The lecturer said a word or two about that, but didnt explained it depply.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Can you think of a way of using Lagrange's theorem to say that a group of prime power order must be cyclic? (And, in general, every group has subgroups that are cyclic. These comments might be getting off topic now, though.)

Comment: accroding to Lagrange's theorem, the order of elements of the a group, which order is prime must devide the order, so it is only itself and 1, so we have only two elemnts of the group, but its order is bigger, so there is the identity and the other, who must be the creator, that is the reason ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:the intersection of two subgroups is also a subgroup. What can it order be in your case?

Comment: Yes, that is what I already wrote.